# Oracle Linux vs Amazon Linux

Tags: oracle-linux, amazon-linux

We are planning to migrate some of the workloads from Azure to AWS. On Azure, we hosted the apps and web applications using Oracle Linux. We are thinking of a migration strategy for this.

Oracle OS: Oracle Linux Server release 7.8

We hosted some Java apps.

1. Can we directly push Oracle Linux to AWS(using DRS or application migration service)?
2. Or do both the platforms are similar package management, so directly install the apps on Amazon Linux?
3. Or something else?

Also, what should consider while migrating oracle linux to Amazon Linux?

Comment: Which version of Oracle Linux do you use, and do you also use the Oracle database?

Comment: I would say just install them on Amazon and test them. Linux distributions always have minor differences so you'll probably need to change the exact procedure, but it should work the same overall